# Source of radar imagery for coastal areas

Tags: data, remote-sensing, hydrography, radar, synthetic-aperture-radar

For my final year research project I need radar images of coastal areas. And can anyone help me to find links where I can download such data free for research purposes?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information: What period of time are you interested in? What temporal and spatial resolution is needed? Any coastline or in special regions?

Comment: In any event, the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is where I think this is more on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The ESA/EU make radar products from the [Sentinel satellites](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/home) available for free through the [Copernicus Data Portal](http://data.copernicus.eu/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe downloading data from the Sentinel platform provided by ESA is very cumbersome. If you are willing to learn javascript, I recommend using the platform provided by Google ([Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com/)).